# Should this website be changed to a general education website with a tag for mathematics education?

Tags: discussion

I think a general education website might be more useful. Then all the education experts can collaborate together on this website instead of just the math education experts. Then questions that would have gone on this website in its current form can be tagged mathematics-education, and all the currently exiting questions could be tagged mathematics-education by a bot.

Answer (score 13):

No.  The people who created this site wanted a mathematics education site, and not a (general) education site.  If you want a general education site, then you should propose a new one at [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/).

There have been quite a few attempts at creating more general education sites and they have failed.  Science Educators sites were proposed [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92559/science-educators/), [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102351/science-educators) and [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113414/science-educators).  Primary and Secondary Education sites were proposed [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110453/primary-secondary-education) and [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110775/primary-and-secondary-education).  Education sites were proposed [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117355/education) and [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/124370/education).  If I'm not mistaken, these proposals were removed because they had "insufficient activity."  (There are likely a few more that I am not aware of.)

A [Computer Science Educators](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators) site is currently in public beta.  But I'm not sure if a more general education site proposal will succeed.

Answer (score 10):

Thank you for all the detail, @Joel.

I have been here since this site's inception. I would not find a general education site nearly as useful to me as this site. If you describe your interests in more detail, maybe people here can help you with a proposal for a new site.

I never used SE before this site existed. I find this site very useful, exactly as-is.